# Is there a way to have event sounds?

Tags: sound, notification, events

Basically, I want to have Ubuntu 11.10 play sounds when events occur, like adding and removing a USB or FireWire device, when it finds hardware, pops up a notification, or mounts a new volume. Like how KDE and Windows does that. Is there a program or a daemon that can monitor for this stuff, or can it be doe a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the built-in Ubuntu sound scheme by replacing the files located in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`.  As far as making Ubuntu play a sound when a drive is mounted there's not really a 'neat' way to do that.  However, if you were to change the autorun settings (system settings -> Removable Media) to a script that plays a sound file and then mounts the drive that would do the trick, but I don't think that's the "right" way to go about it.